# How to sort rows in Theano based on 1st column, then 2nd column, etc

Tags: python, sorting, theano

I have a Theano array that looks like this:

```
0  43  1
4   8  5
0  41  8
4   8  4
```

I want to sort the rows based on the first column, and for rows which have the same value in the first column, sort based on the second column, etc... In this example there are 3 columns but ideally I'd like the method to work with an arbitrary number of columns.

The expected result is:

```
0  41  8
0  43  1
4   8  4
4   8  5
```

Edit: the cells can have very large values (int64), so combining the columns together doesn't look like a viable solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to compute the order list out of Theano in numpy, because one have to deal with tied scenario, which might need if statement.

After you got the order list, convert it to a theano ivector or vector with dtype='int64' or 'int32' and use that as index on the original matrix.

e.g.

```
    0  43  1
A = 4   8  5
    0  41  8
    4   8  4
```

compute order list in nump, which leads to `b = [2,0,3,1]`

```
A = theano.matrix()
order_ls = theano.tensor.ivector(name='orderlist')
reordered_matrix = A[order_ls]
```

to get the value of the reordered matrix, one could create a theano function like

```
get_value = theano.function([A, order_ls], reordered_matrix)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do that with a lexical sort using `sorted`, assuming that your data is formatted consistently like that.

Assuming that this is stored in a text file, you can just do:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as inputfile:
    lines = inputfile.read().splitlines()
    with open('bar.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
        outputfile.write('\n'.join(sorted(lines)))
```

Why? Because space comes before numbers in a lexical sort, so `' 8'` is less than `'10'`, for instance. ASCII was specifically designed for sorts like this.

Comment: While this is true of Python data, a Theano array can't be sorted this way. A symbolic sort is required.

Comment: But why did I get downvoted? My answer satisfies the original question, even if the OP doesn't ask the right question.

Comment: The question is how to sort a *Theano* array. Python's `sorted` function can't do that.